# StackPanel Equivalent In Qt Quick 2 / QML - Problem With Width

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm trying to make an equivalent to wpf stackpanel, I already had a logic and implemented it but something is wrong about width, I don't know how to create new components without getting into width loop binding, here is my stackpanel:

**StackPanel.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import KiMa.Models 1.0
Item {
    id:root
    property var orientation : UOrientation.Horizontal
    property int itemSpacing : 10
    default property list<Item> pageData
    Loader{
        property var childs
        anchors.fill: parent
        id:loader
        onChildsChanged: {
            if(root.pageData != null){
                for(var z = 0;z<root.pageData.length;++z){
                    root.pageData[z].parent = loader.childs
                }
            }
        }

    }
    state: orientation == UOrientation.Horizontal ? "row": "col"
    states: [
        State {
            name: "row"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: loader
                sourceComponent : row
            }
        },
        State{
            name: "col"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: loader
                sourceComponent : col
            }
        }

    ]
    Component{
        id:col
        Column{
            Component.onCompleted: {
                childs = _col;
            }
            id:_col
            width: parent.width
            spacing: root.itemSpacing
        }
    }
    Component{
        id:row
        Row{
            Component.onCompleted: {
                childs = _row
            }
            id:_row
            width: parent.width
            layoutDirection: Qt.RightToLeft
            spacing: root.itemSpacing
        }
    }
}
```

and my orientation enum is like this:

```
#ifndef UORIENTATION_H
#define UORIENTATION_H
#include<QObject>

class UOrientation
{
    Q_GADGET
public:
    explicit UOrientation();
    enum Orientation{
        Horizontal,
        Vertical
    };
    Q_ENUM(Orientation)
};

#endif // UORIENTATION_H
```

and usage example should be like this:

```
StackPanel{
    x: 320
    height: 50
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    anchors.bottomMargin: 25
    Button{

    }
    Button{

    }
}
```

you need to add this into **main.cpp**:

```
qmlRegisterUncreatableType<UOrientation>("KiMa.Models",1,0,"UOrientation","its not creatable type!");
```

This code is working , if you have anything to suggest me to change or you think I made a mistake let me know, the only problem I can see here is width binding.

I already tried using `childrenRect` but it is **not working**:

```
width: childrenRect.width
height: childrenRect.height
```

**Note** : stackpanel allowing you to stack item after item on top of each other you can set orientation to horizontal or vertical so in qt its a column and row together which i made it already.
vertical one :
[image: a vertical stack panel]
horizontal one :
[image: a horizontal stack panel]

Comment: Many do not know how a stackpanel wpf looks or works, you could show a picture of what you want to get

Comment: @eyllanesc i added a note about stackpanel

Comment: Do you need to change dynamically the orientation of the "StackPanel"? If you don't you could just use a `Row` or a `Column`.

Comment: i dont want to use `Row` and `Column ` at all so i created `Stackpanel` so i can set its orientation and it creates me row and col

Comment: Would using GridLayout be an alternative? You can change the number of rows/cols and/or change the flow of the layout depending on your needs. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-gridlayout.html

Comment: @Mailerdaimon because its not grid , i dont need rows and columns , its a basic component look at images , one row line of components

Comment: Yes, and Grid can do this easily. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Mailerdaimon you maybe right here , but anyway my problem is not that , i asked about width

Comment: True, that is why I did not post this as an answer. If you still want to use this approach it would be best to get rid of the StackedWidget part in the question and present the width problem as an [mcve].

Comment: @Mailerdaimon i actually dont want to change this question because i think qml needs a stackpanel which is a completly different thing from GridLayout , yes you can create a stackpanel with GridLayout , but you can create a button using Rectangle too

Comment: But this site is not about what QML needs but about specific programming problem and your description of the Widget distracts from your actual width problem. As you do not want to change your approach leave it out of the description and do not make it a subject to answers.

Comment: @Mailerdaimon true, i shared so much data  about question , i could have made it simpler about width , anyway you can down vote question if you think its not a correct question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this easily with a `Grid` by setting the number of `columns`.
If you want a separate component, you can create your StackPanel.qml with the following:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Grid {
    property int orientation: Qt.Horizontal
    columns: orientation === Qt.Horizontal ? -1 : 1
}
```

[image: QML StackPanel]

If you want a scrollable object, you could also use a `ListView` with an [`ObjectModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-objectmodel.html#details) model. `ListView` has an `orientation` property.

Comment: can i set fixed height for row and fixed width to column of grid?

Comment: problem with this answer is , width or height size of component of stackpanel should be fixed in different orientations i used row and column cause of that